# A-Frame: keep one entity in front of another and facing camera

Tags: components, tooltip, aframe

I want to position and rotate an entity (e.g. an A-Frame [text](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/text.html#introduction) entity) so that it is always just in front of another (e.g. a box), i.e. the text is  positioned slightly in front of the box from the point of view of the camera, facing the camera.  I can use the [look-at](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-look-at-component) component to get the text to face the camera, but I am lost about how to position the text.  I need a generic solution, since the box may vary in size and position, so hard-coding the position of the text won't work.

The aim is to have something like a tooltip that appears in front of the box (once I have the basic idea working, I'll make it so that the text only appears when you are hovering on the box).

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kdva5qxf/1/) ?

Comment: This works beautifully - very clever!  One question though:  how do I stop the `sphericalrig` wireframe showing?

Comment: The answer to my question is in the answer below: use an `a-entity` rather than a `a-sphere`.

Comment: Yeah, kinda that's why I made the answer :) if you find it helpful feel free to mark it

Comment: I'd give it 2 ticks if I could!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, here are two ideas:

**1. Aligning HTML elements with 3D objects**

[This](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/align-html-elements-to-3d) is an amazing resource which is worth checking out (as is the entire [Fundamentals manual](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/fundamentals)), which I used below (simplified, I hope this way the idea is more clear)

The idea is quite simple:

- get the world position of an object
- map it onto the "screen" (x,y) position
- position a `<p>` element with css, using the above x/y values:

```css
p {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  /* let us position them inside the container */
  left: 0;
  /* make their default position the top left of the container */
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* change the cursor to a hand when over us */
  font-size: large;
  user-select: none;
  /* don't let the text get selected */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    schema: {text: {default: ""}},
    init: function() {
       // grab the div, which will contain all <p> elements
       const layoutParent = document.querySelector("#overlays")
       // wait until loaded
       this.el.addEventListener("loaded", evt => { 
        const layoutEl = document.createElement("p") // create the overlay element
        layoutEl.innerHTML = this.data.text          // set the inner text
        layoutParent.appendChild(layoutEl)           // append to the parent
        
        // keep references to use in the "tick" function
        this.layoutEl = layoutEl    
        this.mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
       })
       this.tmpV = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0); // for later use
    },
    tick: function() {
      // ignore if there is no mesh/text yet
      if (!this.mesh || !this.layoutEl) return;
      const tmpV = this.tmpV;
      const canvas = this.el.sceneEl.canvas
      const camera = this.el.sceneEl.camera
      // get the world position
      this.mesh.getWorldPosition(tmpV);
      // get the normalized screen coordinate of that position
      tmpV.project(camera);
      // convert the normalized position to CSS coordinates
      const x = (tmpV.x *  .5 + .5) * canvas.clientWidth;
      const y = (tmpV.y * -.5 + .5) * canvas.clientHeight;
      // move the elem to that position
      this.layoutEl.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
    }
  })
</script>
<div id="overlays">
</div>
<a-scene>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" 
         foo="text: some overlay"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

Hope the comments make it clear - though you should really check the [manual](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/align-html-elements-to-3d)

**2. Using 3D text**

You could calculate the `box -> camera` vector, and use it to offset the overlay text - which combined with `lookAt` should get the effect You're looking for.

A simpler way of the same idea would be:

- create a dummy rig, which would follow the camera using `look-at`
- place a `a-text` in the rig, offseting its *z* by the box bounding sphere radius.

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("spherical-tooltip", {
    schema: {
      text: {
        default: ""
      }
    },
    init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener("loaded", evt => {
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh")
        // the timeout is an ugly hack,
        // the bounding sphere isn't set yet
        setTimeout(evt => {
          const bsphere = mesh.geometry.boundingSphere
          // the main rig
          const rig = document.createElement("a-entity");
          rig.setAttribute("look-at", "[camera]")
          this.el.appendChild(rig)

          // setup the text, and offset the position
          const tooltip = document.createElement("a-text");
          tooltip.setAttribute("color", "black")
          tooltip.setAttribute("value", this.data.text)
          tooltip.setAttribute("align", "center")
          tooltip.setAttribute("position", {x: 0, y: 0, z: bsphere.radius})
          rig.appendChild(tooltip)
        }, 150)
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box spherical-tooltip="text: tooltip" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```